Two sisters kill their father and try to rip off their criminal uncle
Two sisters (older one works as waitress) flee their hometown after killing their father who is molesting the younger one. They go to their uncle (?) where the older one applies for a job as a model. He is involved in some criminal scheme and the older sister tries to rip him off by wooing some private eye who's supposed to make the cash drop.
First scene is the younger sister and her boyfriend in a car, him trying to get to 2nd base but she shrugs him off and goes home where her father and his drunk friends are playing cards.


Bonnie's Kids (1973)

With their mother passed away for several years now, 24-year-old
  Ellie, a coffee shop waitress, and 15-year-old sis Myra live with
  their hard-drinking, abusive stepdaddy Charley. One night after
  losing out to his card-playing drinking buddies, Charley catches Myra
  talking provocatively on the phone to a boyfriend, causing him to slap
  her around and attempt to force his sexual advances. Ellie returns
  home from a hard day’s work to catch this vile display, but instead of
  accepting Charley’s invitation to join in on the action, she blows him
  away with a shotgun. The two sisters hide the corpse and take off to
  San Jose. ~ Edited from DVDDrive-In.com

More info and a pretty detailed plot summary. Also, watch the trailer and/or the full movie :-)
Warning: The videos contain nudity, so definitely NSFW!
